# in ArcGIS js API 4.2, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer replaced with MapImageLayer but AGS services are forced to use the previous version

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying ArcGIS js api 4.2 to generate some services using ArcGIS desktop 10.4.1 and ArcGIS server 10.4.1. but it act so weird for me. i can't see my sercives, all i can see is in this [Screen shot](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8284732050/JS.jpg) that shows just the name of service.

I've done a bunch of search over the internet but there is no solution for this problem apparently. i can't change the ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer.js (which is deprecated in js api 4.2) with "/mixin/MapImageLayer.js" (the righ path in js api 4.2). How can i change the wrong path?